# Tree of trees? Table of trees? What kind of data structure have I created?

Tags: python, database, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I am creating a python module that creates and operates on data structures to store lots of semantically tagged data and metadata from real experiments. So in an experiment you have:

- subjects
- treatments
- replicates

Enclosing these 3 categories is the experiment, and combinations of the three categories are what I am calling "units".  Now there is no inherently correct hierarchy between the 3 (table-like) but for certain analyses it is useful to think of a certain permutation of the 3 as a hierarchy,

e.g. (subjects-->(treatments-->(replicates)))

or

(replicates-->(treatments-->(subjects)))

Moreover, when collecting data, files will be copy-pasted into a folder on a desktop, so data is at least coming in as a tree.  I have thought a lot about which hierarchy is "better" but I keep coming up with use cases for most of the 6 possible permutations. I want my module to be flexible in that the user can think of the experiment or collect the data using whatever hierarchy, table, hierarchy-table hybrid makes sense to them.

Also the "units" or (table entries) are containers for arbitrary amounts of data (bytes to Gigabytes, whatever ideally) of any organizational complexity. This is why I didn't think a relational database approach was really the way to go and a NoSQL type solution makes more sense. But then i have the problem of how to order the three categories if none is "correct".

So my question is what is this multifaceted data structure?

Does some sort of fluid data structure or set of algorithms exist to easily inter-convert or produce structured views?

Comment: You should choose any way to store the information and have an interface to convert to the other kind of structure. If there is only 2 kinds of data representation then it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: That's what I am already doing. I'm asking if there is an API out there I can use to simplify this.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that HDF5 addresses these fairly common concerns and I would suggest it. http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/

In python: http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/group.html
           http://odo.pydata.org/en/latest/hdf5.html

will help.